# Sequence of Locales

Tags: java, localization, internationalization, locale, resourcebundle

What exactly is the sequence in which the Locales are used?
I have 3 properties file:

Dolphins.properties

```
name=The Dolphin
age=0
```

Dolphins_en.properties

```
name=Dolly
age=4
```

Dolphins_fr.properties

```
name=Dolly
```

My code is:

```
5: Locale fr = new Locale("fr");

6: Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "US"));

7: Resource Bundle b = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Dolphins", fr);

8: b.getString("name");

9: b.getString("age");
```

The code sets the default Locale to be Dolphins_en then why does it use Dolphins.properties? What am I missing or misunderstanding?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Resource Bundle Search and Loading Strategy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#default_behavior) ("Once a result resource bundle has been found, its parent chain is instantiated ...")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Default locale is used when selecting the bundle chain. It means, that it will be used when you don't specify it: `ResourceBundle.getBundle("Dolphins")` or when you specify locale where the bundle is not present: `ResourceBundle.getBundle("Dolphins", new Locale("cs"))`.

But when the bundle is selected then the default locale is not used any more for value selection. It means that when the key `age` is not present in *Dolphins_fr.properties* it will use value from the default bundle *Dolphins.properties*.

**Note:** And if the key is not even in *Dolphins.properties* it will throw `MissingResourceException`.

**Update:** I felt that I saw the same code in the past and finally got it. You can look in **Jeanne Boyarsky - OCP Study Guide** or here https://coderanch.com/t/685833/certification/OCP-Chapter-Jeanne-Boyarsky, where is exactly the same code and reasons are explained in a better English.

Comment: You are welcome, I hope it helped to you. Can you please accept the answer then? Thanks